# How to specify JSON array transformation in azure-pipelines.yaml

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pipeline

How to specify JSON array transformation in azure-pipelines.yaml
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/11032

I tried by assigning the parameter of object type but saw Unexpected sequence error.

Comment: Share the task definition you are using, or you can use code to handle the JSON file directly. See my answer. :)

Comment: Hi Yuvaraj, any update of this issue? Have you test the code I provided, let me know if you have more concerns. :)

Answer (score 0):

The task has limitations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops

If possible, please share the YAML definition of your pipeline(or task definition.).

I write a python script which can achieve handling array in JSON file(add, update, remove, get):

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      #get json file parameters.json from Json_Files folder
      
      import os
      import json
      
      def add_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, something_to_add, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              
              #add something to the content
              content.append(something_to_add)
      
              #write the data to json file
              with open(json_file_path, 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
      
      
      
              
      def remove_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, something_to_remove, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              
              #remove something from the content
              content.remove(something_to_remove)
      
              #write the data to json file
              with open(json_file_path, 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
      
      def update_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path, something_to_update_from, something_to_update_to, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              try:
                  #update something from the content
                  content[content.index(something_to_update_from)] = something_to_update_to
              except:
                  print("something_to_update_from is not in the content")
      
              #write the data to json file
              with open(json_file_path, 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
      
      def get_json_content_of_specific_route_in_array_or_bicep_format(json_file_path, json_route):
          length = len(json_route)
          print(length)
          
          #open json file
          with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
              data = json.load(f)
              content = data
              #get the content f data[json_route[0]][json_route[1]]...[json_route[length-1]]
              for i in range(length):
                  if i == 0:
                      content = data[json_route[i]]
                  else:
                      content = content[json_route[i]]
              
              #get the content
              return content
      #==========================================Define the parameters=====================================#
      
      json_file_path = 'Json_Files/parameters.json'
      something_to_add = 'something_to_add'
      something_to_remove = 'something_to_add'
      
      something_to_update_from = 'list'
      
      something_to_update_to = 'something_to_add2'
      
      # route = ['parameters', 'secretsPermissions', 'value']
      route = ['parameters', 'secretsPermissions', 'value']
      
      
      #==========================================Run the function==========================================#
      
      add_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path,something_to_add=something_to_add,json_route=route)
      remove_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path,something_to_remove=something_to_remove,json_route=route)
      update_json_content_of_specific_route(json_file_path,something_to_update_from=something_to_update_from,something_to_update_to=something_to_update_to,json_route=route)
      print(get_json_content_of_specific_route_in_array_or_bicep_format(json_file_path,json_route=route))
```

The test JSON file structure on my side:

[image]